# Role Playing - Can I sell a dungeon map layout that is based on a previous module?

Tags: copyright

I am interested in selling dungeon maps based on previous modules. The one I use for reference is B2: Keep on the Borderlands. If I sell dungeon layouts based on the layouts of that module (but done all from scratch with original art), is there any legal issues I haven't thought about?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This would likely be considered a derivative work. You would need permission from the copyright holder to make it, especially if you intend to distribute it for profit.